# Expressing power law decay in terms of exponentials

Tags: reference-request, exponential-function

**I'm trying to find out how power law decays can be represented, or approximated, by exponential functions.** Any papers or textbook suggestions would be particularly helpful. But in particular, on the following *closed* MathOverflow question

[Is there a way to express an power law decay as a series of exponentials? [closed]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251660/is-there-a-way-to-express-an-power-law-decay-as-a-series-of-exponentials/251661#251661)

Noam D. Elkies suggested the following relationship for relating power law decay to the exponential function:

$x^{-r} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(r)} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{r-1} e^{-xt} dt.$

I have looked for some time online, and also tried and failed to prove this result myself. I'm hoping someone might be able to either show why it's true, tell me which paper/textbook I can find it, or both of the above.

If there are other ways of representing/approximating power law decay in terms of exponentials I'd be interested in those too. At present this is the only paper I have been able to find:

[Optimal approximations of power-laws with exponentials](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0605149)

Comment: That integral you have written follows from the definition of the Gamma function $\Gamma(r) = \int_0^\infty s^{r-1}e^{-s}\, ds$. Then make the substitution $s=xt$ (where $x$ is a positive constant, $t$ is the new integration variable).

Comment: Thanks, I regret that I did not see the substitution before.

Comment: Can you think of any substitution that would work for the above when $t^{r-1}$ could be any function, and $e^{-xt}$ changes to $e^{-x/t}$ ? More explicitly, $x^{-r} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(r)} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t, r) e^{-x/t} dt.$

Comment: If you substitute $\tau =1/t$, the integral becomes $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(1/\tau,r)}{\tau^2} e^{-x\tau}\, d\tau$, which (thinking of $r$ as a constant) is the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of $g(t)\equiv g_r(t):= f(1/t,r)/t^2$. The inverse Laplace transform of $\Gamma(r)x^{-r}$ is $t^{r-1}$, so we would want $f(1/t,r)/t^2$ to be $t^{r-1}$, i.e. $f(1/t,r)= t^{1+r}$, or $f(t,r) = t^{-1-r}$ (where $r > 0$). I think if you use practically any other function for $f(t,r)$, that integral equation will not hold.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and work through that slowly to better understand the details.